# Разница между float и double в SQL

Tags: sql, float, double

В чем разница между `float` и `double`? Везде написано, что `double` аналогично `float`, но с большим диапазоном, но, когда я создавал таблицы, `MySQL` подсказывал, что и у `float(255,30)` и у `double(255,30)` максимальные размерности. Так о какой повышенной точности `double` может идти речь?

И в чем выражается двойная точность `double`? Читал, что `float` хранится в виде экспоненты, а `double` - это двойной `Integer` (целая и дробная часть). Но исходя из статьи на хабре [Что нужно знать про арифметику с плавающей запятой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/)

Мне представляется, что внутри и `float` и `double` будут одинаково хранится в виде мантисы и т.д, только что один займет `4 байта`, а другой - `8 байт`.

Comment: double это не двойной int, он конечно занимает 64 бита, но структура у него такая же как и у float, только больше бит отдано на мантиссу и степень https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: А раз больше бит на хранение то и точность выше. т.к. точное значение хранить невозможно, то хранится ближайшее к нему. И вот это ближайшее у float может гораздо сильнее отличаться от того которое требуется, чем у double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам всё верно представляется - действительно `float` занимает 4 байта, а `double` - соответственно 8 байт. Числа в скобках после указания типа относятся не к тому, как число будет храниться, а к тому, как оно будет представлены в десятичном виде: первый параметр - максимальное общее количество цифр в числе, второй - максимальное число знаков после запятой (например, при указании `FLOAT(7,4)` или `DOUBLE(7,4)` число будет представлено в виде `-999.9999`).

Comment: Хорошо. Но приведите пример, когда я могу положить в double число большее или более точное, чем во float. Потому что теперь у меня впечатление такое, что просто одно занимает 4 байта, а второе - 8.

Comment: @JosephKatzman Создайте таблицу с полем одного типа и другого и вставьте туда скажем `1/3` и сразу увидите разницу. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/198400/1  (правда на fiddle свое округление еще, лучше на реальной БД через какой нибудь MySQL workshop посмотрите)

Comment: такой пример тоже наглядно показывает, где иногда бывает важна точность: `create table test(f float(255,30), d double(255,30)); insert into test values(1.1, 1.1); select f - 0.1 as f, d - 0.1 as d from test;` (оно же на fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af0d2f/2)